# how can i put in label a value from the xml

Tags: xslt

i want a label in my xsl which it's value be one from the xml,
how can i do that?

Comment: Please can you give a little more information? Like an example of some of your XML and XSL?

Comment: in the xml i have a value call:"theAdv"
i want to put this value in a label.
 <xsl:value-of select="theAdv"/>
that is what i want to get:
< label text="@theAdv">

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I think what you want is this:

```
<label text="{@theAdv}">
```

The `{}` allows you to evaluate XPATH expressions inside attribute values.

**EDIT:**
if the text is inside an element and not an attribute you can use the following:

```
<label text="{text()}">
```

`text()` get's the inner text of the current element.